# Keyword 'Zerocon' expected 0 arguments, got 6

Tags: robotframework, keyword

It is  a robot script.

It's  the  Settings.

```
    *** Settings ***
    Suite Setup    GetUrl
    Test Setup     Create HTTP Context    ${conturl[0]["Host"]}
    Library    JsonLibb.py
    Library    RequestsLibrary
    Library    HttpLibrary.HTTP
```

It's  the  Test Cases.

```
    *** Test Cases ***
    Msg
        Log    ${con}
        Run Keyword If    ${con}==1    Zerocon    Onecon
            ELSE If    ${con}==2    Zerocon    Onecon    Twocon
            ELSE    Log    'Error'
```

It's  the  Keywords.

```
    *** Keywords ***
    GetUrl  
        ${conturl}    Get URL Json
        Set Global Variable    ${conturl}
        ${conturl_lenth}=    Get Length    ${conturl}
        Set Global Variable    ${conturl_lenth}
        :FOR    ${url_lenth}    IN RANGE    ${conturl_lenth} 
        \    Set Global Variable    ${url_lenth}  
        \    Log    ${url_lenth}

        ${content}    Get HEADER Json
        Set Global Variable    ${content}
        ${content_lenth}=    Get Length    ${content}
        Set Global Variable    ${content_lenth}
        :FOR    ${con}    IN RANGE    ${content_lenth}
        \    Set Global Variable    ${con}

        ${contbody}    Get BODY Json
        Set Global Variable    ${contbody}
        ${contbody_lenth}=    Get Length    ${contbody}
        Set Global Variable    ${contbody_lenth}
        :FOR    ${body_lenth}    IN RANGE    ${contbody_lenth}
        \    Set Global Variable      ${body_lenth}

    Zerocon
        Set Request Header    Cookie    ${content[${0}]["COOKIE"]}           
        Set Request Header    X-Requested-With    ${content[${0}]["X-Requested-With"]}
        Run Keyword If    '${content[0]["method"]}'=='POST'    POSTRequest
               ELSE If    '${content[0]["method"]}'=='GET'    GETRequest
               ELSE    Log    'ErrorZero'

        Onecon
        Set Request Header    Cookie    ${content[${1}]["COOKIE"]}           
        Set Request Header    X-Requested-With    ${content[${1}]["X-Requested-With"]}
        Run Keyword If    '${content[1]["method"]}'=='POST'    POSTRequest
               ELSE If    '${content[1]["method"]}'=='GET'    GETRequest
               ELSE    Log    'ErrorOne'

    Twocon
        Set Request Header    Cookie    ${content[${2}]["COOKIE"]}           
        Set Request Header    X-Requested-With    ${content[${2}]["X-Requested-With"]}
        Run Keyword If    '${content[2]["method"]}'=='POST'    POSTRequest
               ELSE If    '${content[2]["method"]}'=='GET'    GETRequest
               ELSE    Log    'ErrorTwo'

    POSTRequest
        Run Keyword If    '${url_lenth}'=='1'    HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    ${conturl[0]["Uri"]}
               Set Request Body      ${contbody[0]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    ${conturl[1]["Uri"]}
               Set Request Body      ${contbody[1]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               ElSE If    '${url_lenth}'=='2'    HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    ${conturl[0]["Uri"]}
               Set Request Body      ${contbody[0]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    ${conturl[1]["Uri"]}
               Set Request Body      ${contbody[1]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.POST    ${conturl[2]["Uri"]}
               Set Request Body      ${contbody[2]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               ELSE    Log    "Error"   

    GETRequest
        Run Keyword If    '${url_lenth}'=='1'    HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    ${conturl[0]["Uri"]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    ${conturl[1]["Uri"]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               ElSE If    '${url_lenth}'=='2'    HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    ${conturl[0]["Uri"]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    ${conturl[1]["Uri"]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               HttpLibrary.HTTP.GET    ${conturl[2]["Uri"]}
               Response Status Code Should Equal    200
               Response Body Should Contain    "code":0,"msg":"","data":[]
               Log Response Body

               ELSE    Log    "Error"
```

And  this is the error.

```
       ===========Output============

       Documentation:   
       Runs the given keyword with the given arguments, if condition is true.
       Start / End / Elapsed:   20170317 00:42:03.544 / 20170317 00:42:03.545 / 00:00:00.001
       00:00:00.001KEYWORD Zerocon Onecon, ELSE If, ${con}==2, Zerocon, Onecon, Twocon
        Start / End / Elapsed:  20170317 00:42:03.544 / 20170317 00:42:03.545 / 00:00:00.001
       00:42:03.545 FAIL    Keyword 'Zerocon' expected 0 arguments, got 6.
```

Comment: It is generally good to create the smallest possible code example that allows someone else to recreate the issue. The above question contains too much code and it can not be run to recreate the issue. In addition the code is not explained to what it is supposed to do. Please shorten the example and explain what isn't working and what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that `ELSE If` must be `ELSE IF`. From the documentation (emphasis added):

> Starting from Robot version 2.7.4, this keyword supports also optional ELSE and ELSE IF branches. Both of these are defined in *args and **must use exactly format ELSE or ELSE IF**

The other problem you have, like the error says, is that `Zerocon` doens't take any arguments but you are passing arguments to it. You are passing what looks to be keyword names, but I have no idea what you expect to happen. I don't know if you are wanting to run those keywords, or pass those as arguments to `Zerocon`.

Comment: I just want  to run the keywords when the conditions about ${con}

Answer (score -1):

It's  the  Test Cases.

```
    *** Test Cases ***
    Msg
        Log    ${con}
        Run Keyword If    ${con}==1    Zerocon    Onecon
            ELSE If    ${con}==2    Zerocon    Onecon    Twocon
            ELSE    Log    'Error'
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an answer to the question.